# pull/capture data from sp_HelpConstraint

Tags: sql-server

Within SQL Server 2005 T-SQL, I would really like to pull these columns:

```
constraint_type, constraint_name, and constraint_keys
```

from the output of **sp_HelpConstraint**.  However it returns 3 result sets (2 if you pass in 'nomsg'), so you can't do this to capture it:

```
CREATE TABLE #Constraints
(
...
)

INSERT INTO #Constraints
        (...        )
    EXECUTE sp_HelpConstraint 'TableName', 'nomsg'
```

The only ways I can think of doing this are not good ones:

- just copy the code I need from sp_HelpConstraint
- "fix" sp_HelpConstraint so 'nomsg' removes the last result set too

any ideas?

Comment: SQL 2000 or higher? Very important...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, you're on SQL 2005+
[sys.default_constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189783(SQL.90).aspx) etc to allow standard SELECT

Otherwise, you can use [Information Schema Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778(SQL.90).aspx) on SQL 2000 +

Comment: I'm on 2005.  However sys.default_constraints is OK for column defaults, but sp_HelpConstraint lists check constraints (with full expression) and keys (PK & FK) with formatted column lists, and FK referenced table names.